# Fill color of a text that fits the background with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to fill the texts' background in the shaded rectangle to overlay the dashed arrows, with a color that fits the figure's background.

[image]

I guess I should use the `fill` option with my background gradient color but how to choose the right values ? Is there an option of filling with a transparent color ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 

    \shade[bottom color=gray!10, top color=gray!80] (0,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,4) --++ (-5,0) -- cycle;
    \draw (0,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,4) --++ (-5,0) -- cycle;

    \foreach \y [count =\c] in {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5}{
        \draw [-open triangle 60 reversed,thick](5,\y) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,0.5) node[below right]{$s_\c(\theta_0, t)$};
        \draw [dashed] (5,\y) -- (0,2) node[midway, sloped] {$h_\c(t)$};
    }

    \foreach \y/\couleur [count = \c] in {0.5/red,1.5/purple,2.5/violet,3.5/blue}{
        \pgfmathsetseed{\y+11}
        \draw[\couleur] plot[domain=0:1.5, samples = 500] (\x-5,{rand*0.5*sin(\x*2000)*exp(-3.5*(-\x+1.5))+\y});
        \draw (-6,\y) node {$h_{\c}^*(-t)$};
        \draw [->, shorten >=1cm](-3,\y) -- (0,2);
    }

    \draw (-0.5,2) circle (0.4) node {\Large $\Sigma$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you desire. If you just want the background of the shaded rectangle to be the same as the background just comment out the `\shade`.  Or add `fill opacity=0.2` which will allow some of the background to show thru.  But unless there is an image in the background, changing the `opacity` is just like changing the color.

Comment: Sorry if I explained myself badly, I would like to fill the texts' background in the shaded rectangle, with a color gradient that fits the shaded rectangle. The purpose is to overlay the dashed arrows, I will edit my question.

Comment: My best guess: add a `clip` to the text node and fill again with the same shading in the remaining `scope`

Comment: I do not understand most of the code, but one thing a can give an advice: You can merge the first two commands in your `tikzpicture` to `\shadedraw [bottom…] (0,0) …`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 

    \shadedraw [bottom color=gray!10, top color=gray!80]
               (0,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,4) --++ (-5,0) -- cycle;

    \foreach \y [count =\c] in {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5}{
        \path (0,2) -- (5,\y) node[midway, sloped] (tmp) {$h_\c(t)$};
        \draw [dashed]  (0,2) --(tmp.west) (tmp.east) -- (5,\y);
}


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Remarks : you use `\shaddraw`to avoid the repetition of coordinates for the rectangle. Then you can place the nodes and then you can draw the dashed lines.

[image]

Comment: Much more elegant than my own one.

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

- Do it as you did once.
- Clip the rectangle path of the text node.
- Fill again with the same shading in the clipped area.
- Create the paths with text nodes again, just don't draw them.

Because of the repeating, I put the shading and the path with the text node into macros.

Because the nodes partially overlap, you have to create a new layer on top for the texts. Otherwise, the repeated shading goes over some parts of the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{text}
\pgfsetlayers{main,text}
\newcommand{\shadingmacro}{%
\shade[bottom color=gray!10, top color=gray!80] (0,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,4) --++ (-5,0) -- cycle;
}
\newcommand{\pathmacro}[1]{%
\path [dashed,#1] (5,\y) -- (0,2) node(nod\c)[midway,sloped] {$h_\c(t)$};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 

    \shadingmacro
    \draw (0,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,4) --++ (-5,0) -- cycle;

    \foreach \y [count =\c] in {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5}{
        \draw [-open triangle 60 reversed,thick](5,\y) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,0.5) node[below right]{$s_\c(\theta_0, t)$};
        \pathmacro{draw}
    }

    \foreach \y/\couleur [count = \c] in {0.5/red,1.5/purple,2.5/violet,3.5/blue}{
        \pgfmathsetseed{\y+11}
        \draw[\couleur] plot[domain=0:1.5, samples = 500] (\x-5,{rand*0.5*sin(\x*2000)*exp(-3.5*(-\x+1.5))+\y});
        \draw (-6,\y) node {$h_{\c}^*(-t)$};
        \draw [->, shorten >=1cm](-3,\y) -- (0,2);
    }

    \draw (-0.5,2) circle (0.4) node {\Large $\Sigma$};
\foreach \y [count =\c] in {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5}
{
 \begin{scope}
 \clip(nod\c.south west)--(nod\c.north west)--(nod\c.north east)--(nod\c.south east)--cycle;
 \shadingmacro
 \end{scope}
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}
 \pathmacro{}
 \end{pgfonlayer}
}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works very well. I though the solution would be simpler, I'm not used to scope and clip commands. That's a good opportunity to take a look at it

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the connection node decoration to interrup path and avoid any drawing for the node. The `inner xsep` defines how tight the spacing around the text of the node should be. The rest is pretty much the same.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[mydeco/.style = {
                                   decoration={markings,
                                               mark connection node=my node,
                                               mark=at position .5 with
                                               {\node [sloped,inner xsep=2pt] (my node) {#1};}
                                               },
                                   decorate
                                        }
                       ] 
    \shade[bottom color=gray!10, top color=gray!80] (0,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,4) --++ (-5,0) -- cycle;
    \draw (0,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,4) --++ (-5,0) -- cycle;

    \foreach \y [count =\c] in {0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5}{
        \draw [-open triangle 60 reversed,thick](5,\y) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,0.5) node[below right]{$s_\c(\theta_0, t)$};
        \draw [dashed,mydeco=$h_\c(t)$] (0,2) -- (5,\y);
    }

    \foreach \y/\couleur [count = \c] in {0.5/red,1.5/purple,2.5/violet,3.5/blue}{
        \pgfmathsetseed{\y+11}
        \draw[\couleur] plot[domain=0:1.5, samples = 500] (\x-5,{rand*0.5*sin(\x*2000)*exp(-3.5*(-\x+1.5))+\y});
        \draw (-6,\y) node {$h_{\c}^*(-t)$};
        \draw [->, shorten >=1cm](-3,\y) -- (0,2);
    }
    \draw (-0.5,2) circle (0.4) node {\Large $\Sigma$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]